# Print CoreData Model Recursively without Faults

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I have following Profiler class and from unknown reaseons I can't print story with all faults fired. The printed text contains faults where I have relationships.

```
class StoryProfiler {

let storyId: NSManagedObjectID

init(storyId: NSManagedObjectID) {
    self.storyId = storyId
}

func printToConsole() {

    app().coreDataManager.container.performBackgroundTask { (ctx) in
        ctx.retainsRegisteredObjects = true
        let story = ctx.object(with: self.storyId) as! ModelStory

        // fire all story faults recursively
        _ = story.title
        for cat in story.categories {
            _ = cat.name
        }
        _ = story.listeningMode.name

        for track in story.tracks {
            for l in track.locations {
                _ = l.startTime
            }
        }

        print("BEGIN STORY PROFILER DUMP ====================")
        print(story)
        print("END STORY PROFILER DUMP ======================")

    }
}
```

}

I think I'm doing something really stupid but I can't figre it out why I see faults instead materialized relationship objects.